# Extract elevation data from contour lines

Tags: qgis, elevation, contour

I am working with QGIS. I used raster-extract-contour to get contour lines from a raster image. Now I want to break up my single vector file into multiple layers based on elevation. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that while generating the contour lines. When you define the interval between contour lines in the *Contour* menu, you can provide an attribute name, in which the elevation will be attached as an attribute.

[image]

See also the [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_terrain.html), step 14.

Comment: Please elaborate on how to achieve it in the answer. Links may be broken in the future.

Comment: Good point. Will do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain one layer for every attribute in a specific field then you could to use "Split vector layer" in:

Processing Toolbox >> QGIS Geoalgorithms >> Vector general tools